# Custom service is not loading, as simple as I can make it

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I have created a dataService.j that contains the following:

```
angular.module('dataService', [])
    .service('gameDataService', function() {
        var _gameData = {
        loggedIn: "false",
        gameJoined:"false",
        tableFull: "false",
        username: "",
        tableInfo: {},
        atTable: "",
        numJoined: 0,
        userNames: [],
        numPlayers: _.range(2,7),
        numOfRuns: _.range(1,11)
};

this.gameData = _gameData;

return gameData;
});
```

Then I have my controller module:

```
var client = angular.module('ui_client_ctrl' ,['ui_IO','dataService']);

client.controller('ClientController', function ($rootScope, $scope,gameDataService) {
$scope.gData = gameDataService.gameData;

console.log(gData);
});
```

I am getting the following message:

```
angular.js:13236 ReferenceError: gameData is not defined
at new <anonymous> (dataService.js:18)
at Object.instantiate (angular.js:4619)
at Object.<anonymous> (angular.js:4459)
at Object.invoke (angular.js:4604)
at Object.$get (angular.js:4443)
at Object.invoke (angular.js:4604)
at angular.js:4403
at d (angular.js:4550)
at e (angular.js:4574)
at Object.invoke (angular.js:4596)
```

I have looked at many examples on here and this should work... Any suggestions as to why this is not loading?

Any help would be appreciated,

Z

Comment: you are returning wrong object. you can return `_gameData`, or better `this.gameData` (they share same reference)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you register your service using `angular.module().service()` (in contrast to `factory()` or `provider()`) then angular expects the function you hand it to be something that can be `new`ed. So the function should just add the required properties to `this` (as you did).

Please remove your last line `return gameData;` and try again.

For more details, please see this post: http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/07/07/service-vs-factory-once-and-for-all.html

Comment: The change suggested worked. So if I am reading things correctly, if I was using a factory, then just returning gameData variable would be the only thing required?